# How to optimize a web page containing a select drop down with 3000 options, which is taking too much time to load?

Tags: php, mysql, database

We have a multi-select dropdown with 3000 options. When we try to edit this page, we are fetching all those options and show selected options by default with rest of the unselected options. So when this page-load it takes too much time to load. This functionality is implemented in Drupal 8.

So please suggest what's the best way to implement this functionality. You can suggest in core PHP also if you are not familiar with Drupal.

Comment: I think a dropdown with 3000 options is too big. Maybe you should make smallest sets and use more dropdowns, or a filter or something. Anyway, if we don't see your code or what you are doing it is really difficult even to try to help

Comment: I agree with nacho that you have too many options, and maybe two linked dropdowns would be better. Alternatively you could load the page with zero options, and then populate the list after page load using AJAX.

Comment: usually when you have so many options, the idea could be to use an user input with autocomplete. The user types the first chars of the option and you provide hime those options that match. Or start with, or contains what the user is typing

Answer (score 0):

You could split your dropdowns with submenu dropdowns (with ajax).

If you steel need this menu and it's no need to edit nothing in it:

*Than more Drupal way you use than more time it gets to load all of it.*

(**Not Drupal way practice** but it can solve the issue if necessary):

- You could include this menu directly in html by `hook_footer` (also
  you could do it by another hook like this).
- OR like this:

  ```
  function mymodule_page_build(&$page) {
    $page['page_bottom']['devel'] = array(
      '#weight' => 25, // Some value.
      '#markup' => '<div>Your menu code here</div>',
    );
  }
  ```
- OR you could put it directly to your `html.tpl.php` file

Answer (score 0):

You can use select box auto complete method and set limit 10 or 20 according your choice.